# Why does this void function return an integer even though though there is no return statement?

Tags: c

This code prints 5 even though I am not returning anything in `m()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int abc();
int main(){
    printf("%d", m());
}

int abc(){
    return 5;
}

void m(){
    abc();
}
```

The function is void as well. So can someone explain why 5 is being printed?

Comment: What value would you expect instead?

Comment: Because your code invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @SteveSummit I don't know, maybe some garbage value since i am trying to print the return value of a void function which isn't even trying to return anything.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: The fact that the behavior of the code is undefined by the C standard does not cause `m` to return 5 nor does it cause `printf` to print “5”.

Comment: This doesn't even compile in C99

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Can you refer to some link which talks about this sort of undefined behavior? I came across this in an online discussion group and so was curious because this printed 5 on my system and theirs.

Comment: If you're exceptionally curious, then you should look at the assembly instructions that the compiler generated. Anything else is just an educated guess. An educated guess is that m doesn't disturb the stack when it exits leaving abc's effect in place for printf to address.

Comment: you can look into how printf is implemented with variable length arguments `varargs` it would help to reason out this undefined behaviour

Comment: @VasanthAlagiriswamy: The implementation of `printf` is not relevant to this. The arguments being passed to `printf` would be fully resolved in `main`. So `printf` receives what it normally should receive: a pointer to the first character of a format string and a value matching the conversion specifier. The behavior the OP asks about comes in the code preceding that, when `main` obtains the 5 and passes it to `printf`.

Comment: @Krash That's an okay answer, and as far as the C Standard is concerned, "a random value" is all you can expect to get.  And in fact you *did* get a random value; it just happened to be 5.  (Because in this case, 5 is much more likely than any other random answer, as Eric Postpischil's answer explains.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is common in C implementations for functions to return a value by placing the value in a processor register designated for that value. So what can happen is:

- To return 5, `abc` puts 5 in that register.
- Since `m` does not return a value, it does not change the register.
- When `main` attempts to get the return value of `m`, it reads the register where the return value should be. Since `abc` put 5 there and `m` did not change it, `main` gets 5 and prints it.

None of the above is guaranteed by the C standard, and it is easily disrupted when a compiler performs optimization, so it is not behavior you can rely on in any way.

That said, a C implementation of any quality would report that there are conflicting types for `m`, because its use in `main` either:

- causes an implicit declaration of a function returning `int`, and its explicit declaration later on conflicts with that (for versions of C before 1999 and non-standard versions of C), or
- is a use of an undeclared function name which is not allowed (by later C standards).

Answer (score 3):

From the point of view of the C standard, your code invokes undefined behavior (you're calling a function using a different type signature than the one with which it was defined) and could produce any possible output (or crash or otherwise act unexpectedly).

From the point of view of the implementation, `int`s are presumably returned via a register on your platform / calling convention. So `abc` puts its value into that register. `m` does not touch that register because `m` is `void` and does not return anything. `main` then looks into the register to find the return value of `m` (because `main` thinks `m` is an `int` function) and finds the 5 there.